# Установка imagemagick на windows

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick

1. Скачал [ImageMagick-7.0.2-4-Q16-x86-dll.exe](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php)
2. Прописал путь в переменную окружения PATH.
3. В php.ini `extension=php_imagick.dll` прописываю команду:
   `system("convert img/inp.png img/out.gif");` и ничего.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

включите сообщения об ошибках или

```
$ php -r 'system("convert img/inp.png img/out.gif");';
convert: unable to open image `img/inp.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: unable to open file `img/inp.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3922.
convert: no images defined `img/out.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

"ничего" быть не может, или результат или сообщение об ошибке. если нет сообщения об ошибке - значит они выключены.

возможно, вы забыли рестартовать веб-сервер, и он не подхватил изменений.

если system ничего не выдает, по идее все хорошо. проверьте, что новый файл не создался. потом попробуйте руками вызвать `convert`

и да, почему вы пользуете system для imagick? что за бред? http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php

Comment: `$ php -r 'system("convert img/inp.png img/out.gif");';` Ваш код в редакторе подсвечивается красным, в коде ошибка.

Comment: "$" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: значит вам нужно указать полный путь к php (и заодно включить каталог к нему в PATH), чтобы в будущем не бодаться с этим. Господи, вы со своей консолью разобраться не можете, а уже в веб-девы идете, зочем?

Comment: Мне нужно из файла php: выполнить команду `system("convert img/inp.png img/out.gif");`

Comment: `echo system(аргументы)` выдаст результат выполнения команды. ребут(перезагрузить) компьютер или рестартнуть веб сервер, чтобы он увидел, что imagick  в path добавился

Comment: _ребут(перезагрузить) компьютер или рестартнуть веб сервер_. Это само собой.

Comment: 1. Возможно ли что данная версия imagemagick, не подходит под данную версию windows ? 2. Нужна ли php_imagick.dll если работаю через `system("convert img/inp.png img/out.gif");`?

Comment: цитата: _попробуйте сконвертировать из консоли той же командой_ Через полный путь?

Comment: головой подумай! если через неполный путь не сработает, значит у тебя нет в PATH пути к директории imagick,  тогда пробуй полный. и да, к файлам тоже путь надо указывать или полный или находиться в каталоге в котором каталог img находится.

Comment: цитата: _значит у тебя нет в PATH пути к директории imagick._ Путь указан. Как включить сообщение об ошибках в php.ini?

Comment: гуглом, гуглом. посмотри в гугле, ок?